# Can't get text box on same line as checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a checkbox section. The last option is a text field for a custom entry, but I can't get the field onto the same line as the checkbox.

[Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqMSL.png)

HTML (I included the option before it as well for reference):

```
                <li>
                    <label class="container">Legal
                        <input id="legal" name="legal" type="checkbox" value="1">
                        <span class="checkmark" class="square"></span>
                    </label>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label class="container">
                        <input id="other" name="other" type="checkbox" value="1">
                        <span class="checkmark" class="square"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input id="otherText" maxlength="40" name="otherText" size="10" type="text" placeholder="Other...">
                    <span class="bar" style="width: 150px;"></span>
                </li>
```

CSS:

```
#otherText{
        font-size:.9em;
        width: 150px;
        display:block;
        border:none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

#otherText:focus { outline:none; }
```

Comment: maybe `display: inline-block` for `#otherText` ?

Comment: Could you add a code snippet? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I would personally set up a grid system. If you have Bootstrap already incorporated, you can use the `row` and `col` classes respectively. If you do not use Bootstrap, then I would recommend using Flexbox.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was with the "container" class, which I didn't even provide the code for here. Sorry everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
        <li>
                <input id="legal" name="legal" type="checkbox" value="1">
           <label class="container">Legal
                <span class="checkmark" class="square"></span>
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label class="container">
                <input id="other" name="other" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <span class="checkmark" class="square"></span>
            </label>
            <input id="otherText" maxlength="40" name="otherText" size="10" type="text" placeholder="Other...">
            <span class="bar" style="width: 150px;"></span>
        </li>
```

CSS -

```
   li {
      display: flex;
    }
```

[image]

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Try display:inline, rather than display:block for your #otherText input. Check out [this page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) for info about display options.

Comment: Nope, inline and inline-block don't fix it.

Comment: Please could you post more of your CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks as if `inline-block` will make a difference, and so did removing your `color:#fff` line:

```css
#otherText{
        font-size:.9em;
        width: 150px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:none;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

#otherText:focus { outline:none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="container">Legal
      <input id="legal" name="legal" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <!--span class="checkmark" class="square"></span-->
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="container">
      <input id="other" name="other" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <!--span class="checkmark" class="square"></span-->
    </label>
    <input id="otherText" maxlength="40" name="otherText" size="10" type="text" placeholder="Other...">
    <span class="bar" style="width: 150px;"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As I did not see any merrit in your `<span class="checkmark">` I commented them out out .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the "container" class. It was set to display: block.

To solve, I removed the "container" class from the "other" option, and assigned it a unique id with all of the same styling except for display: block.

Answer (score 0):

OP eventually found the solution on their own, but I would like to add something for future reference. I often in time see Flexbox being overlooked.

Flexbox is a great tool for exactly these kind of problems, which rely on grid. I would encourage everyone to read up on Flexbox, especially these properties:

1. flex-direction
2. flex-wrap
3. flex-grow
4. flex-shrink
5. flex-basis
6. justify-content
7. order

If you master these 7 properties, then grid troubles will be something of the past.
Pair it with `max-width` properties, `padding`, `margin` and what else you'd need to make the grid fit your design.

Often at times, CSS frameworks, such as Bootstrap, can be quite overkill if the project is of a small nature. CSS frameworks should only be justified if you can utilize multiple aspects of it over a larger project. Using Bootstrap for grid alone is not ideal. With that said, Bootstrap does offer a very powerful grid layout with the use of the classes `row` and `col`. It's worth reading up on.

**Example of using flex with the current problem at hand:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="1" />
        <span class="cb-text">Dev Team</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="2" />
        <span class="cb-text">Product Manager</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="3" />
        <span class="cb-text">Security / SecOps</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="4" />
        <span class="cb-text">DevOps / CI/CD</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="5" />
        <span class="cb-text">Legal</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="6" />
        <input type="text" class="cb-text other-text" placeholder="Other..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 650px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cb-container {
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
}

.cb-element {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

input.other-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 65%;
    max-width: 65%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #B3B3B3;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
```

**Snippet Example:**

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 650px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cb-container {
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
}

.cb-element {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

input.other-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 65%;
    max-width: 65%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #B3B3B3;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row container">
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="1" />
        <span class="cb-text">Dev Team</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="2" />
        <span class="cb-text">Product Manager</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="3" />
        <span class="cb-text">Security / SecOps</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="4" />
        <span class="cb-text">DevOps / CI/CD</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="5" />
        <span class="cb-text">Legal</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row cb-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" value="6" />
        <input type="text" class="cb-text other-text" placeholder="Other..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/OJRKvod).

**Useful links:**

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/